# MySQL giving weird error

Tags: mysql

What is wrong in the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM forms 
LEFT JOIN form_fields ON forms.id = form_field.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN form_options ON form_field.id = form_options.parent_id 
WHERE forms.name = activities
```

MySQL says 'unknown column 'activities'' where obviously forms.name should be seen as column name

Comment: After replacing the where clause with '1' it starts about forms.id which is definately an existing column

Comment: As it stands, `activities` needs to be an unambiguous column name on one of the tables `forms`, `form_fields` or `form_options`. Did you mean to filter on the *value* 'activities' (single quotes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just missing the quotes, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM forms 
LEFT JOIN form_fields ON forms.id = form_field.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN form_options ON form_field.id = form_options.parent_id 
WHERE forms.name = 'activities'
```